# Since upgrading to 2.5.5, Template Manager links broken in Chrome.

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades

Since upgrading to 2.5.5, in the Template manager screen, all the links have the same template group ID in them, so I can't switch between template groups. It works in Firefox, Opera, and even in IE, just not Chrome. Wondering if anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Any Javascript errors? I believe that's how those links are generated.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'refreshPrefs' in admin.php, line 1339

Gah, should have checked that first. Sorry. Anyway, that did lead me to a post on EllisLabs that *might* be related, but it's several months old and didn't help much: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227831/#1034943

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest reuploading the control panel theme files from your 2.5.5 install. Perhaps something was corrupted on upload. The files are stored at: /themes/cp_themes/.

Also, make sure the page has completely loaded in Chrome before clicking on the template group.

Also, check the Chrome Dev Tools Network Panel for any 404 errors.

Comment: I've reinstalled the themes, and am sure the page completely loads. The `Object #<Object> has no method 'refreshPrefs'` error only shows up in Chrome, Firefox (and even IE) work fine (with no errors or warnings in Firefox's console). 

At this point, i do not have any time left to track down why this is happening (among the however-many add-ons I'm using). But on the bright side, this led me to find [the QuickEE extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/quickee) which has actually improved my template access situation.

Comment: A Google search found this thread on the EE forum which shows the same error: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227831/#1034943. It seems like a reinstall is what worked for this person which doesn't sound like the optimal solution.

Comment: Reuploading all the themes folder worked for us. I don't know how the hell I forgot to upload this folder! thank you Anna!

Answer (score 0):

Strange, just had this happen to me after upgrading to 2.6.1. Replacing the cp_themes directory didn't fix the issue, but replacing the whole themes one did.

Who knows. Hope this helps someone else.